# How do I filter for ECR images created in the past week

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am using the boto3 api, but open to using CLI if it gives any more flexibility.

```
client = boto3.session.Session(profile_name="prod").client("ecr", region_name="us-east-1")
response = client.describe_images(repositoryName=repository_name)
```

What I used to do is do above and just filter on date by using `sorted(response["imageDetails"], key=lambda x: x["imagePushedAt"])`. However, I am only getting 90 responses, and wondering if this is an internal limit.

I see that there is a `filter` argument to `describe_images` and I tried to do it by doing the following but get the error: `*** botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed: Unknown parameter in filter: "Name", must be one of: tagStatus Unknown parameter in filter: "Values", must be one of: tagStatus`

```
import datetime

date_filter = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
filter={"Name": "imagePushedAt", "Values": [date_filter+"*"]}
response = client.describe_images(repositoryName=repository_name, filter=filter)
```

Any thoughts on how to filter ECR images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at the BOTO3 documentation for (ecr.describe_images)[https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecr.html#ECR.Client.describe_images], you will see a few things:

- An optional `nextToken` parameter
- An optional `maxResults` parameter

The `nextToken` is used to iterate and get additional batches of results. The function is limited to 100 results per batch by default, though you can push that up to 1000 if you want. If (or when) you have more than 1000 images in your repository you can't avoid using the pagination support, alas.

You can use the `client.get_paginator()` approach, if you prefer. Below, I'm building on top of what you already started with, though.

The other thing you'll note in the documentation is the `filter` parameter, which is indeed fairly limited as you noticed.

You mentioned finding 90 images, which suggests that you had 10 images from before the last week, in those first 100 images.

Here's *one way* to iterate over all images, and checking the `imagePushedAt` of each of them:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3
import datetime

my_profile = "prod"
my_region  = "us-east-1"
my_repo    = <repository_name>

date_threshold = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print("date threshold = {}".format(date_threshold))

batch = 0
image = 0
total = 0
client = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=my_profile).client("ecr", region_name=my_region)
nextToken = {}
while True:
    response = client.describe_images(repositoryName=my_repo, **nextToken)
    batch = batch + 1
    print("Batch {}:".format(batch))
    for entry in response["imageDetails"]:
        total = total + 1
        if entry["imagePushedAt"].strftime("%Y-%m-%d") >= date_threshold:
            image = image + 1
            print("  Image #{}/{}: {} pushed at {}".format(image, total, entry["imageDigest"], entry["imagePushedAt"]))
    if "nextToken" in response:
        nextToken = { "nextToken": response["nextToken"] }
    else:
        break

print("Done - {} batch(es), {} images match out of {}".format(batch, image, total))
```

If you would like to go in batches of more than the default 100 at a time, you can add that `maxResults` parameter in the `describe_images()` call.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm relatively new to SO, and not quite sure what it means when it says that you are "looking for an answer from a reputable source.". Do all bounties say that? Regardless, I've been programming for over three decades and running a significant production environment in AWS for several years now, with many (longer/shorter) Python/boto3 scripts.

Comment: Hey, should have thanked you ages ago, but I finally got around to using this and saved my skin. Thank you. You're awesome! Don't worry about reputable source, you ARE the reputable source.

Answer (score 0):

My Python is pretty rusty but I had this same requirement recently.  Leaned on ChatGPT a bit to get started (hence the mixed in snake case).  I wanted the last x ECR images uploaded to a repo based on date.  Boto3 seems to have a bit of a gap here (or at least it wasn't obvious that I could just easily specify such a filter as the input).

```
def getLastEcrImages(ecrCli, repoName, numToFetch):
    response = ecrCli.describe_images(repositoryName=repoName)
    image_details = response['imageDetails']
    sorted_images = sorted(image_details, key=lambda k: k['imagePushedAt'], reverse=True)[:numToFetch]
    image_tags = [(image['imageTags'][0], image['imagePushedAt'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) for image in sorted_images]
    return image_tags
```

In my case I converted the resulting list of objects to a simple menu where the user just picked one.